# Cannot read property 'AccountNumber' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-chrome

i know undefined problems is usually does with assignment. But I can access the values of properties directly

in enum.ts

```
export enum Account {
    AccountNumber = "account number",
    FirstName = "first name",
    LastName = "last name",
    Token = "email address",
    Age = "age"
};

export enum Espenses {
    Mortgages = "mortgages",
    ...
};
```

in estimator.ts

```
import * as EstimateEnums from ./enum.ts

estimateEnums = EstimateEnums;

private myEstimate: Estimator;
this.myEstimate = {
Account: {
    AccountNumber: 1,
    FirstName: "name1",
    LastName: "name2",
    Token: "dw@mail.com",
    Age: 41
    },
Espenses: {
    Mortgages: 100...
}

Object.entries(this.estimateEnums).forEach(([key,value]) => {
    Object.entries(value).forEach(([key2,value2]) => {
    console.log(this.myEstimate.Account.AccountNumber) //prints 1 
   console.log((this.myEstimate[value.toString([key2.toString()]))});//error is here
});
```

error line should print 1

Comment: what is value of `key2` ?

Comment: Evaluates to AccountNumber. key2.toString() evaluates to 'AccountNumber'

Comment: fixed it. Object.entries(this.estimateEnums).forEach(([key,value]) => {
   Object.entries(value).forEach(([key2,value2]) => {
    console.log(this.myEstimate.Account.AccountNumber) //prints 1 
    console.log((this.myEstimate[key.toString()])[key2.toString()])
   });
  });